# Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug in react native Failure : Build failed with an exception

Tags: react-native

multiDexEnabled true in android/app/build.gradle

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug
> com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/xxxxxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3f59ce583c6cc3a5866ca18087adc6f6/jars/classes.jar
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:600)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.reportException(ForkJoinTask.java:678)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.join(ForkJoinTask.java:722)
> at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:146)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.transform(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:420)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
> at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor376.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
> at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:47)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:284)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:301)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:293)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:258)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:67)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:145)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:69)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:50)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SnapshotOutputStep.execute(SnapshotOutputStep.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:134)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.lambda$execute$3(CacheStep.java:83)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:82)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.PrepareCachingStep.execute(PrepareCachingStep.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:23)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:34)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:91)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:91)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:119)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.execute(ResolvePreviousStateExecuter.java:43)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:93)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:45)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:94)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:56)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:67)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:315)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:305)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:175)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:101)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/saroja/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3f59ce583c6cc3a5866ca18087adc6f6/jars/classes.jar
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:909)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.lambda$convertToDexArchive$6(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:834)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1447)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:177)
> Caused by: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing.
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:124)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:101)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexArchiveBuilderTransform.launchProcessing(DexArchiveBuilderTransform.java:904)
> ... 7 more
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:70)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withD8CompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:43)
> at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:94)
> at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveBuilder.convert(D8DexArchiveBuilder.java:99)
> ... 8 more
> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzb is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_messaging.zzc`.
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.failIfPendingErrors(Reporter.java:89)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:60)
> at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:64)
> ... 11 more

> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /User/xxxxx/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/3f59ce583c6cc3a5866ca18087adc6f6/jars/classes.jar

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warning

Thanks advance. i tried every thing no result.  help me frnds

Comment: What things did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem, I tried to update the following imports in the **build.gradle** file with the latest versions, but it didn't work

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution here https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1979

Update the react-native-push-notification dependency to 7.3.1